# How to make my item with selector too?

Tags: android, styles, spinner, selector

When I Click in the Spinner the item don't make blue too. My item is a custom item which has a background with selector (gray and blue when pressed).

[image]

Comment: Make the background transparent?

Comment: I tried but didn't work.

Comment: Now i change all background of the custom item to @android:color/transparent and worked, thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only change all backgrounds of views from custom item to "@android:color/transparent" and worked.